# Test if string is "*"

Tags: string, bash, variables, if-statement

For some reason I just cannot get an if statement to test if a string is literally equal to an asterisk. I have tried every combination I can think of and I don't want to mess with file globbing. Please help.

```
if [ $VAR = "\*" ]; then
```

*** UPDATE ***

Both of those suggestions work. The issue is apparently not with the * comparison, but with the other part of the if statement. This is supposed to compare whether or not `$VAR` is between 0 and 20 or is a wildcard.

```
if [ "$VAR" -gt 0 ] && [ "$VAR" -lt 20 ] || [ "$VAR" = "*" ]; then
```

This other part of the IF statement if apparently goofing up the last comparison.

*** UPDATE ***

Just tested it again and checked my syntax. When `$VAR` is between 0 and 20 it works great (true), when `$VAR` is over 20 it also works (reports false), however as soon as I try to set `$VAR` to an * the if statement freaks and pops out:

```
line 340: [: *: integer expression expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version using bash's [double brackets](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031):

```
if [[ $VAR = "*" || ($VAR -gt 0 && $VAR -lt 20) ]]; then
```

The double brackets allow you to use `&&` and `||`. Also, bash doesn't perform word splitting or glob expansion on arguments to `[[`, so `$VAR` doesn't need to be quoted and `(` doesn't need to be escaped.

`[[` also works in zsh and ksh, if you need (some) portability.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ VAR="*"
$ if [ "$VAR" = "*" ] ; then echo Star ; fi
Star
```

Quote variables when they could contain glob patterns, whitespace or other interpretable sequences you don't want interpreted. This also avoids syntax errors if `$VAR` is empty.

For your second problem, `[ "$VAR" -gt 0 ]` doesn't make sense if `$VAR` is anything but a number. So you must avoid having that test evaluated in that case. Simply exchange your tests  - `||` and `&&` are short-circuiting (in bash at least, not sure if that's POSIX):

```
if [ "$VAR" = "*" ] || [ "$VAR" -gt 0 -a "$VAR" -lt 20 ] ; then
```

Comment: Nope, still get line 336: [: *: integer expression expected

Comment: You have two demos showing that this works. Are you sure that's the same statement you're talking about? Can you post exactly what you have now?

Comment: Ok actually this DOES work. The issue is apparently with my if statement. ie I have it compare if a number is greater than 0 AND less than 20 OR equal to *

Comment: See my update above. Your examples worked. It is another part of my IF statement that is goofing it all up.

Comment: I think `-a` is deprecated. You should use `{ [ "$VAR" -gt 0 ] && [ $VAR -lt 20 ] ; }` instead.